# How to use all cpu in dask?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cpu, dask

[image]

Trying to process dataframe in parallel through dask.

But it doesn't seem to be using all the cores of the cpu.

How do I use up all the cores?

partitions is set to 50 and code is

```
dd_df.to_parquet('./test_parquet', compute_kwargs={'scheduler':'processes', 'nums':20})
```

Comment: Can you run `print(dd_df.npartitions)`? It might have fewer partitions that you have cores available.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev print(dd_df.npartitions) is 50. Should I increase the number of partitions more?

Comment: Hmm, no, I think that's already more than the number of cores you have. Do you see the same pattern if you use `dd_df.to_parquet()` without the `compute_kwargs`?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Yes, At first, only to_parquet() was executed

Comment: In general, it may depend on how your dataframe was made. If you use the distributed scheduler, the dashboard will give you more information. Remember, however, that you might easily be IO-bound, as you only have one disk.